# Is it possible to have conditional 'FETCH NEXT X ROWS ONLY' by checking the result set count

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql

I'm using oracle client in .net framework (c#) and need to limit the number of records returned in case where number of records are bigger then **X**

When constructing sql I understand I can append `FETCH NEXT X ROWS ONLY` if I first execute the query to get the count against the sql I'm constructing and if count exceeds **X** I can append `FETCH NEXT X ROWS ONLY` statement.

I'm curious is it possible to achieve that in one shot rather then getting the count and appending fetch next if count exceeds **x**

Comment: Not sure what's the use case for this. For example, if I want the to display a maximum  of 100 rows and also tell the user "there are more rows", I typically limit to 101. If I receive 101 rows back, then that means there are more than 100, all the while limiting the effort in the database.

Comment: Use case is that the user want to query entire table across field A B or C (depends on selection) for the distinct values. In some cases return set is big, exceeds 40k records and since I'm using wpf listview loading that many records are going to crash the app.
Instead we limit the records returned to 300 and display warning that the result set is not full. Now sometime the number of records are less than 300 and warning is still up which is misleading. I've 'solved' the problem by hiding showing warning based on result set count, if it's < 300 warning stays but it's not the best solution

Comment: Why would you *count* anything? You want to return at most **X** number of rows, so append FETCH NEXT X ROWS ONLY unconditionally. Suppose X = 100; if number of rows query returns is 72, it'll return 72 rows (i.e. everything). If number of rows query returns is 203, it'll return 100 rows (i.e. limited number of rows - limited by the value of **X**). Or did I not understand the question?

Comment: let's say I have fetch next 300 rows only introduced, but the query returns 45 records, in that case my warning stays (unless I do what I've explained in my previous comment, count and compare the result with 300)
I was just curious if you'd be able to construct sql that would conditionally have 'fetch next ...' statement

Comment: What warning? You don't need such a query. I suspect you confuse client-side paging with `FETCH NEXT X ROWS ONLY`. The count is only needed to calculate the number of pages. `FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY` is used *without* change in all page queries. The only thing that may change is the omission of `OFFSET X ROWS`, since you don't have to skip any rows in the first page. In every subsequent page `OFFSET` is used to skip over the previous rows, eg `OFFSET 50 ROWS`, `OFFSET 100 ROWS`

Comment: UI Warning presented to the user that what he is seeing in ListView is not complete result set, but only first X (300) records

Comment: @krul As I said if you never display more than 300 rows, then limit to 301. If you get 300 or less, you just display them, and no warning is necessary. If you get 301 you display the first 300 (ignoring the last one), this time displaying the warning. This is pretty much a standard solution for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment, if you never display more than 300 rows, then limit to 301:

```sql
select *
from t
fetch next 301 rows only
```

Upon receiving the result, there are two cases:

- If you get 300 rows or less, you just display them, and no warning is necessary.
- If you get 301 rows you display the first 300 (ignoring the last one), this time displaying the warning. Easy, isn't it?

This is pretty much a standard solution for this case.

Comment: Easy indeed! I should have thought of that :), Now I see you suggested this right of the bat thanks!

_Not sure what's the use case for this. For example, if I want the to display a maximum of 100 rows and also tell the user "there are more rows", I typically limit to 101. If I receive 101 rows back, then that means there are more than 100, all the while limiting the effort in the database._

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want get a limited number of rows and a count of the total number of (unfiltered) rows at the same time. In which case, use the `COUNT(*) OVER ()` analytic function in a sub-query and then limit the rows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER () AS num_rows
  FROM   table_name t
)
ORDER BY id
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, value) AS
SELECT LEVEL, CHR(64+LEVEL)
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE();
```

Outputs:

| ID | VALUE | NUM_ROWS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 |
| 2 | B | 10 |
| 3 | C | 10 |
| 4 | D | 10 |
| 5 | E | 10 |

You only get 5 rows but you also get a column with the total number of rows in the unfiltered result-set.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nlLNmgyC)

Comment: That's OK if the OP only wants to show a sample of the data. It would be very expensive if it was used in a paging query

Comment: This can be a killer on an overwhelmed database.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the number of rows fetched using ROWNUM ...
Your actual query in all codes below comes instead of ( Select * From tbl )

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  tbl AS
    ( Select 'A' "DUMMY" From Dual Union All 
      Select 'B' From Dual Union All 
      Select 'C' From Dual Union All 
      Select 'D' From Dual Union All 
      Select 'E' From Dual Union All 
      Select 'F' From Dual 
    )
```

... just be aware of order by as it affects the order of rows fetched

```sql
Select  * From tbl Where  ROWNUM <= 3
/*  R e s u l t :
DUMMY
-----
A
B
C     */
```

...

```sql
Select * From  tbl Where ROWNUM <= 300
/*  R e s u l t :
DUMMY
-----
A
B
C     
D
E
F       */
```

... Or with a NOTE, but that includes counting first which you don't  want as I understood the question.

```sql
SELECT  x.DUMMY, Case When ROWNUM = 4 Then NOTE End "NOTE"
FROM    ( Select  t.*, 
                  Case When Count(t.DUMMY) OVER() > 4 
                        Then 'There are ' || To_Char(Count(*) OVER() - 4) || ' more rows to be fetched!' 
                  End "NOTE"
          From   ( Select  * 
                   From  tbl 
                 ) t
        ) x
WHERE ROWNUM <= 4
/*    R e s u l t :
DUMMY NOTE                                                                       
----- --------------------------------------
A                                                                            
B                                                                            
C                                                                            
D     There are 2 more rows to be fetched!    */
```

This way you will not have conditional FETCH NEXT but conditional NOTE column (with some text) in the last row fetched but just when there are some more rows left behind. Maybe that you could use in your app.